# Can mipmaps be used to compute dot product?

Tags: opengl, gpu, gpgpu, metal, mipmaps

Imagine there're 2 vectors in GPU memory - `a` and `b`, which are in fact 2D `float` textures (1 float value per pixel). The goal is to compute the dot product `a·b`.

If I create a third texture - `c` - which contains the element-wise product of `a` and `b` (i.e. `c_{ij} = a_{ij} × b_{ij}`), then the sum of all pixels' values is the dot product.

I thought I could let the GPU generate 1px mipmap of `c` - let's call it `d`. AFAIK `d` is the *average* of all pixels in `c`, which if multiplied by appropriate LOD of the mipmamp would result in the dot product.

**Questions**

- Is it possible to compute the dot product in the way described above?
- Would such approach be faster than computing the dot product via compute kernel?

For concrete example of API let's consider Apple's Metal API or OpenGL/CUDA.

Comment: You'll probably lose a lot of precision from the mipmapping step.

Comment: I highly doubt that this would be faster than executing a kernel. Simply the data arrangement and reordering might kill the performance.